# Openlayers switching source of ImageStatic causes the memory to increase by about 5 megabytes

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks, openlayers

I have 4 difference maps that are png files. I'm using openlayers to switch between them every 10 seconds. Here is the code:

html div: `<div id="map" class="map"></div>`

```
  function myFunctionThatGetsCalledEveryTenSeconds(){
   var mapImage = getTheNextImage();
   setMap(mapImage);
  }

  function setMap(currentMap) {
    $('#map').empty();

    var extent = [0, 0, currentMap.map_width, currentMap.map_height];
    var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
      code: 'map',
      units: 'pixels',
      extent: extent
    });

    layerImage = new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        imageExtent: extent,
        imageLoadFunction: function (image) {
          image.getImage().src = currentMap.image_url;
        }
      }),
      name: "map"
    });

    map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      logo: false,
      layers: [layerImage],
      controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attribution: false,
        zoom: true,
      }),
      view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
        zoom: 3,
        minZoom: 0.5,
        maxZoom: 5
      })
    });
  }
```

Everytime the source of Imagestatic is changed (image.getImage().src = currentMap.image_url;), The memory used by the browser tab increases by about 5 megabytes. Tested chrome browser. I'm using chrome://system/ to monitor the memory usage. Eventually the memory consumption gets to high and the tab crashes.

What am I doing wrong?